# SQL Query with row_number() not returning expected output

Tags: sql

my goal is to write a query that should return the cities which produced the highest avg. sales for each item-category.

This is the expected output:

```
item_category|city
books        |los_angeles
toys         |austin
electronics  |san_fransisco
```

My 3 table schemas look like this:

```
users
user_id|city

sales
user_id|item_id|sales_amt

items
item_id|item_category
```

**These are further notes to consider:**

1. sales_amt is the only column that may have Null values. if no users have placed a sale for a particular item-category (no rows in sales with a non-Null sales_amt), then the city name should be Null.
2. only 1 row per each distinct item. It more than 1 city qualify, then pick the first one alphabetically.

The attempt I took looks like this but it does not produce the right output:

```
select a.item_category,a.city from (
select 
i.item_category,
u.city,
row_number() over (partition by i.item_category,u.city order by avg(s.sales_amt) desc)rk 
from sales s 
join users u on s.user_id=u.user_id 
join items i on i.item_id=s.item_id
group by i.item_category,u.city)a
where a.rk=1
```

My output does not return the Null cased for sales_amt. Also, I get non-unique rows. Therefore, I am very nervous I am not properly incorporating the 2 notes.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Why do you partition your row number by city also? You actually want row number to increment within a category only, having 1 where the highest avg is, and from this you then get the city. If you partition by city too then every city will be rank 1

Comment: Are you also saying that if you never sold item X it will have a record in sales with a null amount? That's weird. I would have expected more like the items table would have a record of X but there would be no rows in the sales table for X

Comment: "Only one row per item" - did you mean "item category"?

Comment: @CaiusJard thank you for the feedback. To answer: I may not need partition by city as you said since I can group by city and item_cat to get the results. The reason for the nulls in sales_amt is the case when a customer placed an order for an item X but this item was not in stock anymore (lag in warehouse syncing). And yes, I want 1 row for each item_cat and city (with the highest avg sales_amt).

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You've tagged three...

Comment: @Lroy_12374 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @dalek I don't suppose it matters for this one; they all support the query as presented

Comment: It should be noted that the accepted answer does not address a few points made in the question and comments and will produce the wrong result in some cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaand my take on it is a mix of GMB and Gordon's advices; GMB points out that left joins are needed but I think his starting table, partition and choice of rank() is wrong (his query cannot generate null city names as requested, and could generate duplicates tied on same avg), and Gordon picked up on things like ordering by city on a tied avg which GMB did not but missed the "if no sales of any items in category X put null for the city" requirement. Both guys left cancelled orders floating round the system which introduces errors:

```
select *
from (
    select
        i.item_category,
        u.city,
        row_number() over(partition by i.item_category order by avg(s.sales_amt) desc, u.city asc) rn
    from items i
    left join (select * from sales where sale_amt is not null) s on i.item_id = s.item_id 
    left join users u on s.user_id = u.user_id 
    group by i.item_category, u.city
) t
where rn = 1
```

We start from itemcategory so that categories having no sales get nulls for their sale amount and city.

We also need to consider that any sales that didn't fulfil will have null in their amount and we exclude these with a subquery otherwise they will link through to users giving a false positive - even though the avg will calculate as null for a category that only has cancelled orders, the city will still show when it should not). I could also have done this with a `and sales_amt is not null` predicate in the join but I think this way is clearer. This should not be done with a predicate in the where clause because that will eliminate the sale-less categories we are trying to preserve

Row number is used on avg but with city name to break any ties. It's a simpler function than rank and cannot generate duplicate values

Finally we pull the rn 1s to get the top averaging cities

Answer (score 1):

> my goal is to write a query that should return the cities which produced the highest avg. sales for each item-category.

This can be calculated using aggregation and window functions:

```
select ic.*
from (select i.item_category, u.city,
             row_number() over(partition by u.item_category order by avg(s.sales_amt) desc, u.city) as seqnum 
      from users u join
           sales s
           on s.user_id = u.user_id join
           items i
           on i.item_id = s.item_id
      group by i.item_category, u.city
     ) ic
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your question explicitly says "average" which is why this uses `avg()`.  However, I suspect that you really want the sum in each city, which would be `sum()`.

Notes:

- You want one row so `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.
- You need sales to calculate the average, so `join`, instead of `left join`.
- You want one row per *item_category*, so that is used for partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `left join`s starting from `users` in the inner query to preserve cities without sales.

As for the ranking: if you want one record per city, then do not put other columns that city in the partition (your current partition gives you one record per city and per category, which is not what you want).

Consider:

```
select *
from (
    select
        i.item_category,
        u.city,
        rank() over(partition by u.city order by avg(s.sales_amt) desc) rk 
    from users u
    left join sales s on s.user_id = u.user_id 
    left join items i on i.item_id = s.item_id
    group by i.item_category, u.city
) t
where rk = 1
```